# Signature files for document retrieval

Tags: file, document, signature, information-retrieval

I was wondering if you know somewhere where I can find information on how to build a signature file for docuement retrieval. 
Do you know if there is some code out there that I can use or look at?
I have to create a signature file in C++ under linux platform.

**UPDATE: Sorry, I appreciatte the help but I was refering to signature files not as a way to validate documents but as a way of indexing documents.



http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_files**



Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at [Semantic Hacker](http://www.semantichacker.com/) or [Yahoo Term Extraction](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, lets clarify some terminology.

A Digital Signature is intended to be equivilent to a handwritten signature (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature for a better description and overview).

When a digital signature is applied to a document you get a higher level of assurance of the authenticity of the document (you have a better idea if the document was forged or not).

The answers from Adam and Robert both refer to methods for verifying document integrity (that the document is unchanged). While a digital signature also provides this, a checksum (hash) does not provide authenticity.

So it's important that we establish the needs of your "Signature file". I will assume that you are talking about Digital Signatures, rather than checksums as the other answers address checksums.

You will want to compose a PKCS#7 detached signature (jargon - a standard format signature that does not contain the data, so it can be stored seperately). To acheive this I recommend you use a standard library such as OpenSSL (which is portable).

- For more information on PKCS#7 see http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2129
- For more information on  OpenSSL see http://www.openssl.org/

Answer (score 0):

[md5sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) might be what you are looking for. Source code for generating md5 signatures is available if you Google around.

From Wikipedia:

> Because almost any change to a file
>   will cause its MD5 hash to also
>   change, the MD5 hash is commonly used
>   to verify the integrity of files
>   (i.e., to verify that a file has not
>   changed as a result of file transfer,
>   disk error, meddling, etc.). The
>   md5sum program is installed by default
>   in most Unix, Linux, and Unix-like
>   operating systems or compatibility
>   layers. BSD variants (including Mac OS
>   X) have a similar utility called md5.
>   Versions for Microsoft Windows do
>   exist.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to Adam's suggestion, if you're working on a very large amount of documents, it might be a good idea to check out SHA1 and sha1sum.  Less collisions, and a bit more advanced encryption.